# How to store one JS array into different arrays based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have one javscript array variable which is each array element having object value

```
 {"ID":10075,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":11,"GROUPID":1}
```

and entire JSON.stringify value like below...

```
 "[{"ID":10075,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":11,"GROUPID":1},
  {"ID":10076,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":14,"GROUPID":1},
  {"ID":-1,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":0,"GROUPID":0},
  {"ID":10077,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":11,"GROUPID":2},
  {"ID":-1,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":0,"GROUPID":0},
  {"ID":10078,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":92,"GROUPID":3}]"
```

how to store array value in different arrays' base on ID value is -1 
my output should be:-

First array having 2 record which id are :- 10075,10076

second array having 1 record which id is :- 10077

third array having 1 record which id is:- 10078

Comment: basically you need grouping by ``GROUPID`?

Comment: Luckily you have an array, so `array.prototype.forEach` should help you here.

Comment: Thanks for you ans...But GroupID is not corrected its just for your information i have written... it is possible?.. i need to divided based on id = -1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the items separated by the item with `ID === -1`. This proposals works with a result set and a group array for the actual group.

You could use either `thisArg` from [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var array = [{ ID: 10075, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 11, GROUPID: 1 }, { ID: 10076, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 14, GROUPID: 1 }, { ID: -1, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 0, GROUPID: 0 }, { ID: 10077, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 11, GROUPID: 2 }, { ID: -1, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 0, GROUPID: 0 }, { ID: 10078, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 92, GROUPID: 3 }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this.group || o.ID === -1) {
        this.group = [];
        grouped.push(this.group);
    }
    if (o.ID !== -1) {
        this.group.push(o);
    }
}, { group: null });

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or a closure over a `group` variable in the callback of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var array = [{ ID: 10075, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 11, GROUPID: 1 }, { ID: 10076, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 14, GROUPID: 1 }, { ID: -1, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 0, GROUPID: 0 }, { ID: 10077, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 11, GROUPID: 2 }, { ID: -1, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 0, GROUPID: 0 }, { ID: 10078, SPECIALIZATIONID: "17", PRESPCIALIZATIONID: 92, GROUPID: 3 }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (group) {
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!group || o.ID === -1) {
                group = [];
                r.push(group);
            }
            if (o.ID !== -1) {
                group.push(o);
            };
            return r;
        };
    }(), []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The result is in both cases a new array with arrays of the grouped items of the given data. The items with `ID === -1` are not included.

Comment: Thanks for you ans...But GroupID is not corrected its just for your information i have written... it is possible?.. i need to divided based on id = -1??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the ones with GROUPID different than 0

```
function arrayParse(value){ 
    var result = [];

    value.forEach(function (v) {
        if (v.GROUPID) {
            if(!result[v.GROUPID])
                 result[v.GROUPID] = [];
            result[v.GROUPID].push(v.ID);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you ans...But GroupID is not corrected its just for your information i have written... it is possible?.. i need to divided based on id = -1??

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array.prototype.filter() to create a function that would return array filtered by group id.

```js
var array = [{"ID":10075,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":11,"GROUPID":1},
  {"ID":10076,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":14,"GROUPID":1},
  {"ID":-1,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":0,"GROUPID":0},
  {"ID":10077,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":11,"GROUPID":2},
  {"ID":-1,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":0,"GROUPID":0},
  {"ID":10078,"SPECIALIZATIONID":"17","PRESPCIALIZATIONID":92,"GROUPID":3}];

function getGroup(groupId){
 return array.filter(function(object){
 return object.GROUPID === groupId;
});
}
var group0 = getGroup(0);
var group1 = getGroup(1);
var group2 = getGroup(2);
console.log(group2);
```

Comment: Thanks for you ans...But GroupID is not corrected its just for your information i have written... it is possible?.. i need to divided based on id = -1??